# How to add photo from my android application to my facebook album page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an android application that creates an image.

I would add this image in an album of my facebook page (and not in my personal wall).

I see that i must use the [app token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/).

i get the app token with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=MY_APP_ID
    &client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET
    &grant_type=client_credentials
```

And then with this app token I think that i must use this code:

```
String appToken="MY_APP_TOKEN";
facebook.setAccessToken(appToken);

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("caption", "This is a message test...");
byte[] ImageBytes=...;
parameters.putByteArray("photo", ImageBytes);

String response2=facebook.request("ALBUM_ID/photos", parameters, "POST");
```

This code return this error:

```
A user access token is required to request this resource
```

Then i must not use app token?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need an user access token to make API requests on behalf of the user.  You should use our Facebook Android SDK to provide an easy way for users to authorize your app.  Our SDK also makes it easy to fetch the access token after the user authenticates, follow our [Android tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) here if you have more questions.

App access tokens are different from user access token, this is taken from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/).

> Authenticating as an App allows you to obtain an access token which allows you to make request to the Facebook API on behalf of an App rather than a User. This is useful, for example to modify the parameters of your App, create and manage test users, or read your application's insights for example.

Let me know if that answers your questions.

Comment: Sorry for the delay to answering.
Ok, I dont'use App token but I must use User auth.

    `String[] Permission={"publish_stream","manage_pages"};
    facebook.authorize(this, Permission, new DialogListener()`
but with `facebook.request("111122223333444/photos", parameters, "POST");` I get "Invalid album ID"

Comment: that's because 111122223333444 is an invalid user id

Comment: Hehe :-) in this answer I have used a dummy ID. I have used this command `https://graph.facebook.com/194913980639419/albums` to find the album ID that is (I put it anyway) `194915017305982`. This is the Album of my page where i should put the image created by android app. `It is an honor / pleasure for me to discuss with a facebook developer:-D`

Comment: 194915017305982 is a valid album ID.  However, this is on a Facebook Page, so only the Page itself can upload photos or the user who owns that page.  I think you also need the "manage_pages" permission also for this case.

Comment: I chose to add the photos directly to a user's album without going through the application / page.
Thanks for everything.
Hello and good work!